# Modifier returning modifier

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development

So basically I'm trying to make something like that.
Btw. Logic is not important.

```
modifier validateValue(uint fee){ if(msg.value != ((0.1 ether) * fee)) revert(); _; }

modifier checkFee(address payOutAddr){
    uint begin = 30 * uint(payment[phoneBook[payOutAddr]].paymentsCount);
    uint end = begin + 15;
    uint cycleOfContract = now - startDate;
    if(begin < cycleOfContract && cycleOfContract < end){
        return validateValue(1);
    }
    else {
        uint totalFee = (int(cycleOfContract/30) + 1) * 0.02 ether;
        return validateValue(totalFee);
    }
}
```

I want to make a modifier returning modifier, but this can't compile. Is there a way to make something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use a function `validateValue` instead of returning modifier from a modifier. I think the following code should solve the problem. I don't have your complete code so I could not test it, but hopefully, this will work.

```
modifier checkFee(address payOutAddr){
    uint begin = 30 * uint(payment[phoneBook[payOutAddr]].paymentsCount);
    uint end = begin + 15;
    uint cycleOfContract = now - startDate;
    if(begin < cycleOfContract && cycleOfContract < end){
        if(!validateValue(1,msg.value)) revert();
        _;
    }
    else {
        uint totalFee = (int(cycleOfContract/30) + 1) * 0.02 ether;
         if(!validateValue(totalFee,msg.value)) revert();
        _;
    }
}

function validateValue(uint fee, uint amount) constant returns (bool){
    if(amount != ((0.1 ether) * fee)) return false; 
    else return true;
}
```